# iOS : In app purchase. Product is paid or free based on user type

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I am developing an iOS application & I am going to sell products in application based on user type after user login.

If user is of Type A [ Privileged User] 
  Then he can download product totally free / Based on promo code / Purchase if Promo Code is InValid (That I can decide based on some flags).

If user is of Type B [ Normal User] 
  He have to pay for product & then he can download it on successful payment.

But, I have doubt about it whether Apple is going to approve this or not. At the time of submission of application to app store, I will provide them Normal User (User of Type B) credentials so that they can buy it normally.

Is this approach is right or wrong ?

Other way is, I can set same product with two different identifiers on iTunes connect. 
One for free & another for purchase one.

When user logs in based on user Type I can decide which products to load for that user based on product identifiers which I have with me.

Is there any alternate solutions for same ?

Has anybody gone through same scenario ?

Thanking You !

Comment: how do you separate the different types of users on the fly when they are purchasing the application from AppStore?

Comment: user have to register & privileged user will receive some code in email through which they will be registered as special user at the time of registration.

Comment: Rephrase your question as “I want some users to have access to a product without making them buy it in the App Store” and I think you can answer it.

Comment: @DavidDunham .... You are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a free app in the store that was using in-app purchases to enable features.  I also had a place to enter promo codes which could also enable features.  It was rejected by Apple because of the ability to enter a promo code and bypass the app store.  Sounds like the same as what you are trying to do.

Comment: I doubt that this is against their policy. In principle a promo code can be seen as a single log in to gain extra features. There are plenty of apps who allow you to log in to get content you would normally only get through in-app purchase... Unless you add a buy button to get a subscription outside the app store, it is not against their policy. I think the same holds true for promo codes (so don't provide a way to get a promo code from within the app)

Comment: Promo code's will be mailed to users as we have email ids of privileged users. App will only have option to enter promo code if userType is privileged user. If promo code is invalid then they can buy. Normal user will have only option to buy.

Comment: That's what I did, emailed promo codes to users, but Apple said the field in the app where they enter the code is not allowed. I now instead I just update my server so it knows which users get free access, end of problem.  YMMV, I didn't try appealing it with Apple, I just changed it.

Answer (score 2):

I have one thought, don't know whether the Apple test engineers will allow it or not, keep in app purchase for non-privileged user and for privileged user instead of asking them to enter the promo code inside the application, update their privilege from WS (IF you are sending them promo code via email that means you have their email ids or user ids with you), make some provision inside the application to identify this and make functionality unlock. Never tried this but for one of my in-app purchase application was not rejected even though it has a flaw in it, when I put the subsequent build version the app got rejected and I needed to correct that flaw. It was about restore purchase button. Once your app is in appstore they don't look further into it. Its just a thought but you need to think before taking the risk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can really do it that way. The app can only be free, if it's free. But you can't have the app do nothing if no promo code is entered. Therefore, the best solution seems to be to have a free version of your app with minimal functionality. Privileged users can use the promo code (you cannot link to a site where you can buy this promo code though!) and normal users will have to do an in-app purchase to get the extra functionality.

Hope this helps!

Comment: my solution... you need a free version for your promo users

Comment: I don't want two applications. I want one application with both functionalities.

Comment: you will have one application! a free application... with some but limited functionality. the promo code will unlock all features, or an in-app purchase will unlock all features.

Comment: Problem is not about unlocking features...New products are available monthly basis & then based on userType & promo code products will be free or paid for particular user only.